# Iterating through object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following dummy data on my code:

```
const resorts = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    name: "Lakawon Island Resort",
    price_per_night: 2804.0,
    description:
      "On a lush 16-hectare island with white-sand beaches, this relaxed resort is 5 km from the jetty in Cadiz Viejo, a village on the mainland.",
    address: "Cadiz Viejo",
    city: "Cadiz",
    province: "California",
    zip_code: "6121",
    latitude: 11.045411,
    longitude: 123.201465,
    contact_number: "(034) 213 6354",
    website: 'www.lakawonislandresort.com',
    amenities: 
      {
        tv: false,
        reservation: false,
        moderate_noise: true,
        free_wifi: true,
        trendy: true,
        credit_card: true,
        bar: true,
        animals: true,
        kids: true
    },
    image:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512356181113-853a150f1aa7",
    rating: 4.5,
    reviews: 11,
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    name: "Bluewater Maribago Beach Resort",
    price_per_night: 4156,
    description:
      "Set in a complex of thatch-roofed buildings on the Cebu Strait, this posh beachfront resort is 1 km from Mactan Island Aquarium and 4 km from the Magellan Shrine.",
    address: "Buyong",
    city: "California",
    province: "Maribago Mactan Island",
    zip_code: "6015",
    latitude: 10.290899,
    longitude: 124.000822,
    contact_number: "(032) 402 4100",
    website: "http://www.bluewater.com.ph/",
    image:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e",
    rating: 3.5,
    reviews: 35,
    amenities: 
      {
        tv: true,
        reservation: true,
        moderate_noise: false,
        free_wifi: false,
        trendy: false,
        credit_card: false,
        bar: true,
        animals: true,
        kids: true
    }
  }
```

On one of my components I am trying iterate on the `amenities` property so I tried the following codes:

```
const { name, address, city, province, zip_code, image, description, amenities } = resortsList

 <div>
               { 
                  Object.entries(amenities).forEach(
                    ([key, value]) => {
                        if(value){
                            return `<p>${key}</p>`
                        }
                    }
                )
               }
            </div>
```

This doesn't show the paragraph key if the value of the key is true.

Its only showing me blank on my HTML. Any idea whats causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`

```
              { 
                  Object.entries(amenities).map(
                    ([key, value]) => {
                        return value ? <p>${key}</p> : null;
                    })
               }
```